# Why does EC2 allow QEMU/KVM 32 bit VMs to run, but not 64 bit?

Tags: virtual-machines, windows-10, aws-ec2

The setup is EC2 with 8 cores and 32GBs of memory running Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop. Virtual Machine Manager has been installed. I downloaded 32 bit and 64 bit Windows 10. I'm able to create a VM using 32 bit Windows that successfully boots and installs.  Windows 64 bit attempts to start but almost immediately errors out with a blue screen citing "SYSTEM THREAD EXCEPTION NOT HANDLED". I am trying to understand why 32 bit works, but 64 bit fails?  The EC2 instance is missing the VMX flag, but is that strictly necessary to run a 64 bit VM?

Thanks